# How to set the JSTL variable value through javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jsp

I would like to display *html* code when the user clicks on a particular box.

When the user selects a value from one of the available options, a JavaScript function is invoked which stores the selected value against a variable.

I am having difficulty with implementing code to compare the value of **EL** variable with the **innerHTML** variable.

Below is the code I am currently using:

```
var groupid = parseInt($('#selectgroup').val());    

document.getElementById("facilityTable").innerHTML= "<c:forEach var='group' 

items='${groups}'>"+
"<c:if test='${group.key == (groupid)}'>"+

"<td>+Test+${group.value.groupName}</td>"+

"<td>${group.value.groupId}</td>" +                                                                                     

"</c:if>"+

"</c:forEach>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *JSTL* tags will not be a part of *JS* output, so there is not reason to put them into quotes, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById("facilityTable").innerHTML= ""
<c:forEach var='group' items='${groups}'>
  <c:if test='${group.key == (groupid)}'>
+ "<td>+Test+${group.value.groupName}</td>"+
"<td>${group.value.groupId}</td>"                                                                                     
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>;
```

Comment: but can,t get groupid vaule in <c:if test='${group.key == (groupid)}'>.

Comment: groupid variable is declare in javascript var groupid = $('#selectgroup').val();

Comment: You can not use JS variables in JSTL EL expressions, because they are executed on the server **before** user gets result Html and JS starts execution. You can use JSTL to render groups as JS array. And then iterate through it using simple JS for loop.

Answer (score -2):

**Set to jstl variable value using javascript**

```
<script>
    function function1()
    { 
        <c:set var="temp" value=""/>
        temp="Hello";
        alert(temp);   
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no connection between the JSTL variable `temp` and the global JS variable `temp` here.